# grouping all segments of data which belongs to one perticular model

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, speech, hierarchical-clustering

I have an array of arrays,

```
a=[sp1 sp2 sp3...spN]
```

Here sp1,sp2 are also arrays of some data points like

```
sp1=[1 2 3....100]
```

I am doing some processing on first two index of array means on sp1 and sp2.
I will get some value, either that value will be positive or negative,

CASE 1:
If that value is positive then I will label sp1 as "S1" and sp2 as "S2".

CASE2:
If that value is negative then I will merge two data set ie) sp1 and sp2 and label as S1 ie) S1=[sp1 sp2];

Then at next step I will move forward for first [case 1] I will do the same processing between S1 and sp3 and same one between S2 and sp3... and same CASE 1 AND CASE2 process should happen for the second [CASE 2] I will do processing in between S1 and sp3.

Please suggest something I'm stucked here.

Basically I'm trying to do homogeneous speaker clustering. I'm having speaker segments. Now I'm trying to grouping of all segments belongs to particular speaker.

If my audio file is having 2 speaker,and after segmentation I got 30 segments. Now I want to cluster the segments belongs to speaker 1 and label it as "S1" and cluster the segments of second speaker and label it as "S2". For clustering I'm using BIC criteria. That is all fine but what should be the coding flow? I tried a lot, but could not figure out...

Comment: please any suggestions